# Is it possible to reload only a certain compontent in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, reload

I was wondering if I have a Vue component, which has other components in it. Is it possible to only load a certain component.

So If I would have a component like this:

**Main component**

```
<template>
<button>Button<button>
<component1></component>
<component2></component2>
</template>
```

Is it possible to only reload component 1 on click of button 1?
If so how would I only reload that certain component?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload
location.reload() might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a good article about forcing an update for a component:
https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

So basically you add a `:key` to your component and increment a number by clicking your button

```
<component1 :key="num" />

<button @click="num++" v-text="'update'" />
```